# sublime text installation, and how to run it

Tags: sublime-text

how to install sublime text in UBUNTU? 
And also, what is the command to run the application and I also want to know how to program using sublime text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 is available from the [official Sublime Text repository](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html). The following information was taken from the documentation available at that page.

In order to use the repository, install their signing key:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Make sure your apt supports https:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

Add an entry for the repository to your apt configuration:

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Install Sublime Text using apt

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sublime-text
```